# Parse remote csv on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

I keep getting the error file name is too long.
I am running rails on Heroku so I am trying to have an uploaded file saved on cloud, and then imported so it is not lost on their dyno.

I want to create a new object for each row in the csv. Parsing the CSV has worked perfectly before in development when using a temp file. But I have to change this for Heroku.

What is wrong about my code for the remote csv being parsed correctly?

```
def self.import_open_order(file_url)

    open(file_url) do |file|
      CSV.parse(self.parse_headers(file.read), headers: true) do |row|
...
```

Comment: Is the csv file so large that you don't want to commit it with the app on push?  If not, just add it to your apps root folder and commit it then push. Then you can grab it from within the app and avoid the url issue.

Comment: It's a new csv file uploaded every day during the week

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it

```
 def self.import_open_order(file)
    imported_file = open(file)
      CSV.parse(self.parse_headers(imported_file), headers: true) do |row|
```

Since `open(file).class = Tempfile`... I was able to just create the Tempfile and pass it through `CSV.parse`

I swear I had already tried this but now it works!